# Having this error of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which stops me from continue my loop iteration

Tags: java, java-io

I was working on my assignment and trying to read data from my text file. While I was trying to store those information to different array one by one, an error like this occur

But with the console output, it shows that it actually did run through the first iteration but it occur this error and stop it

This is my code below

```
public static void readFile() {

    cucibleID = new String[100];
    name = new String[100];
    matricNo = new String[100];
    date = new String[100];
    spvName = new String[100];

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String readLine = sc.nextLine();



            String[] splitted = readLine.split("\t");

            for(int i=0,j=0; i< splitted.length;i++) {

                cucibleID[i] = splitted[j++];
                name[i] = splitted[j++];
                matricNo[i] = splitted[j++];
                date[i] = splitted[j++];
                spvName[i] = splitted[j++];

                System.out.println(cucibleID[i] +" "+ name[i]);
            }

        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my error output in my console .... (Remarks: `1L5 John` in this below is from `System.out.println(cucibleID[i] +" "+ name[i]);`)

```
1L5 John
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at ASSN1.main.readFile(main.java:99)
    at ASSN1.main.main(main.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the point of the `for` loop? Why are you trying to extract 5 values X times? Re-think what you're doing, e.g. the `i` variable should increment once for each iteration of the outer `while` loop, and there should be no inner loop, since you know (well, expect) each line to have 5 values, you just get them directly, as in `cucibleID[i] = splitted[0];`, since the `cucibleID` is the first value in the line.

Comment: Quite similar to your last question this one doesn't contain enough info to identify the issue. I can make an educated guess, but it remains just that: a guess. You'd best include the file content up until the line after the one containing the `John` content. (My guess being that not resetting `j` to 0 at the start of every loop iteration makes you try to refer to parts of the split that don't exist (2nd iteration refers to the fifth part the first time there's a read access to the array).)

Comment: Oh yaa I think I have some serious logic problems. Thanks Andreas

Comment: Thanks fabian I think I get what you mean

Comment: Actually index 5 is the 6th part... Got a little inattentive there...

Comment: If you have a `TSV (Tab Separated Value)` file, use an API to process it. https://www.univocity.com/pages/about-parsers

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this:

```
public static void readFile() throws IOException {
    cucibleID = new String[100];
    name = new String[100];
    matricNo = new String[100];
    date = new String[100];
    spvName = new String[100];
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath())) {
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; (line = in.readLine()) != null; i++) {
            String[] splitted = line.split("\t");
            cucibleID[i] = splitted[0];
            name[i] = splitted[1];
            matricNo[i] = splitted[2];
            date[i] = splitted[3];
            spvName[i] = splitted[4];
            System.out.println(cucibleID[i] +" "+ name[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Changed `Scanner` to `BufferedReader` because `Scanner` is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain, what your for-each loop does. Assuming the length of your splittet array is 5.

First iteration:

- `i = 0; j = 0;`
- Line with cucibleID -> `i = 0; j = 0;` and `j++` that
  means j will be `j = 1;`
- Line with name -> `i = 0; j = 1;` and `j++`
  that means j will be `j = 2;`
- Line with matricNo -> `i = 0; j = 2;`
  and `j++` that means j will be `j = 3;`
- Line with date -> `i = 0; j =
  3;`  and `j++` that means j will be `j = 4;`
- Line with spvName -> `i
  = 0; j = 4;`  and `j++` that means j will be `j = 5;`
- End of first iteration. `i = 0` -> `i < 7` -> `i++`

Secound iteration

- `i = 1; j = 5;`
- Line with cucibleID -> `i = 0; j = 5;` and the ArrayIndexOutOfBound will happen

As you can see from my example is the following:
You are having the correct index `i` for your splitted array, but you are using `j` as index.
The following code will set your arrays correctly at index 0, assuming your splitted array has 5 elements

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0; 
if(splitted.length == 5) {
    cucibleID[i] = splitted[j++];
    name[i] = splitted[j++];
    matricNo[i] = splitted[j++];
    date[i] = splitted[j++];
    spvName[i] = splitted[j++];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop. Use `j` for the elements in the splitted record.
`j` should start at 0 for every record.
Use `i` for the processed record.

You probebly had to add some extra logic to deal with record with less than 5 elements

```
public static void readFile() {

    cucibleID = new String[100];
    name = new String[100];
    matricNo = new String[100];
    date = new String[100];
    spvName = new String[100];
    int i = 0;

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String readLine = sc.nextLine();
            String[] splitted = readLine.split("\t");
            int j = 0;

            cucibleID[i] = splitted[j++];
            name[i] = splitted[j++];
            matricNo[i] = splitted[j++];
            date[i] = splitted[j++];
            spvName[i] = splitted[j++];

            System.out.println(cucibleID[i] +" "+ name[i]);

            i++;

        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just took the liberty of adding a declaration variable declaration for `j` and fixing the one for `i`. You could roll back the edit, if you don't want to go back to your version...

Answer (score -1):

add a check before accessing array index

```
  String[] splitted = readLine.split("\t");
 for(int i=0,j=0; i< splitted.length;i++) 
{ 
  if(splitted.length > j)
    cucibleID[i] = splitted[j++]; 
 if(splitted.length > j)
    name[i] = splitted[j++]; 
if(splitted.length > j)
    matricNo[i] = splitted[j++]; 
if(splitted.length > j)
    date[i] = splitted[j++]; 
if(splitted.length > j)
    spvName[i] = splitted[j++];     
  if(cucibleID.length >i && name.length >i)
  System.out.println(cucibleID[i] +" "+ name[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Can't use `splitted` in `for` loop header if it's declared *inside* the loop. Besides, what is the point of splitting the same `readLine` multiple times?

Comment: I tried but still same output buddy.. but thanks for helpp

Comment: Becaus the line in the text file is followed by id, name, matricNo, date, spvName with a \t as delimeter

Thats why I split them and save into the array individually. Or is there any better way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this removes the exception, but does not result in the behaviour Ng Jing Xuan expects. This seems a kind of CSV (tabs) taking the place of commata in this case.

Comment: well, source code can't fix if problems with input data, it can only handle problems gracefully

Comment: What do you believe the input is? Question doesn't specifically say, bu the only thing that makes sense to me, disregarding the bad logic in the question code, is that the file is a tab-separated text file, with 5 values per line. That's why there is a loop reading *lines*, and there are 5 arrays of 100(?) values for reading up to 100 lines from the file. The index into the 5 arrays should be line number, so indexing with `i`, which iterate the values of one line, makes no sense whatsoever. Why would each line begin assigning to `[0]` each time? The `for` loop is bad, and so is this answer.

Comment: there is a reason of believing in that because array index of bound value is 5 in exception logs, So, if it have crossed that 100 lines boundary, it should have a bigger index.